# Unusual display of a list of strings on Colab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

This may be considered as trivial but I do like to know what's going on to improve my technology literacy. When I run [this notebook](https://github.com/blueprints-for-text-analytics-python/blueprints-text/blob/master/ch01/First_Insights.ipynb) on **Google Colab**, the value in the column `tokens` is a list of strings/words. However, the strings/words were not enclosed with quotient marks. Is that a feature of **Colab** or I have missed something? Thanks.

[image]

PS: The column `tokens` was derived from the column `text` with standard cleaning process of tokenizing (split a string into words) and removing stopwords.

Comment: Bizarrely, the quotes seem to appear if you nest the string in four lists of more: e.g. `pd.Series([[[[["test"]]]]])` vs `pd.Series([[[["test"]]]])`.

Comment: Very interesting. Would you please share how you discovered this? Thanks

Comment: I saw this by testing a list that contains itself: `lst = ["test"]; lst.append(lst)`.

Comment: But the output of  `lst = ["test"]; lst.append(lst)` is `['test', [...]]` so I couldn't see how that led to your discovery :(

Comment: It shows up when you pass it to `pandas`: `pd.Series([lst])`.

Comment: if code runs without problems then stop bother this.